# how to subscribe jms in other program?

Tags: spring, jms

I try to make example project using spring and jms.
so, I refer a site(https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/).
However, when i run the server, i don't know how to subscribe message in the other program.
please give me some hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the code, author has used destination name as - "mailbox-destination". When you need to receive a message, you need to listen to the same destination. Author has also given the code of Receiver. Please take a look at src/main/java/hello/Receiver.java.

You will need the same code in other application to receive the message. If you would like to try some more examples, take a look at :

[receive message using direct message listener](http://shengwangi.blogspot.in/2014/10/spring-jms-with-activemq-helloworld-example-recv-direct.html)

[receive message using message listener adapter](http://shengwangi.blogspot.in/2014/10/spring-jms-with-activemq-helloworld-example-recv-via-adapter.html)

Comment: Thanks for advise. However, I want to subscribe message in the other program. so, I ask. If i use this Receiver class in the other program separated server program, can i receive the message?

Comment: Do you wanna say that receiver code is running on any other server? If this is your question, answer is yes. Make sure that you are using the correct jms server url and destination name.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll find how to set the server url, etc.